# What battery should i use for a bluetooth boombox?

Tags: batteries, amplifier, 12v

I've been searching for 3 days now to find an answer to this problem. I have a TDA7492p amplifier(8v-24v input) and I am looking for a battery that is safe to be charged while using the amplifier. The VRLA 12v 7Ah seems perfect but they say it's very dangerous and hard to recharge(needs very exact volts and amps). Another solution would be laptop cells, but they seem hard and expensive to recharge. Theoretically both are designed to charge while being used but I don't know what is the best way. Do I need a special circuit/device for that? And how should I power the boom box to also charge and use it?

Comment: Either should have a charging circuit or controller. Do not attempt to charge by just injecting power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only chemistry that I can think of that's relatively safe, and in fact what I've chosen for *my* portable boombox, is SLA, sealed lead acid.

Charged at the float voltage, 2.3v per cell, or 13.8v for a 12v battery, it will accept that voltage indefinitely, without degrading significantly. The slight overcharge current is tolerated by the gases recombining within the cell. This process has a limited rate, so the maximum float voltage (to limit the overcharge current to what can be absorbed) must be strictly observed.

The maximum charge current needs to be limited as well, to protect it when it goes back on charge after a lot of use.

Do be aware that lead acid does not like deep discharge cycles. If you limit discharge depth to 50%, you will get an order of magnitude more life out of the battery than if you allow 100% discharges.

These characteristics suit my style of use quite well. It can be on float charge permanently when at home. The 'normal' run time is at the 50% capacity rating, and if stuck away from home, the extra 50% capacity is regarded as an emergency reserve, that I can use occasionally.

I discounted VRLA (valve regulated) as they tolerate overcharge by venting, and have to be topped up with distilled water from time to time.

Comment: The lead-acid batteries in burglar / intruder alarm systems are permanently float charged at about 13.8V without problems. Generally these are VRLA batteries such as the NP series from [Yuasa](http://www.yuasa.co.uk/batteries/industrial/np-vrla-general-use/np7-12l.html). What a lot of people call SLA are really VRLA batteries. Look at the Maplin advert for [SLA batteries](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/yuasa-12v-sealed-lead-acid-battery-7ah-1-pack-mg47b). If you look at the photo of the battery it is Valve regulated.